# unix Syntax error near unexpected token 'done'

Tags: shell, unix, while-loop

This script

```
#!/bin/sh
once=true

while $once do
stop & PID=$!
sleep 10M

if [$!=0]; then
start
break
else
kill $PID
fi

done
```

Gives

```
./restart.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./restart.sh: line 18: `done'
```

I don't understand, it had run previously on another unix system. Am i missing something?

EDIT

`stop` and `start` are functions that simply run `stop.sh` and `start.sh` respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing a semicolon on line 4.  Modifying it to read

```
while ${once}; do
```

should fix it.